# Проблемы с деплоем

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Ситуация следующая:
http://webmaster.ayrveda.ru/dist/
в режиме разработки проект работает нормально проблем нет.

при деплое я прописываю путь следующим образом:
router: {
base: '/dist/'
},

на хостинге это выглядит вот так:
[image: http://joxi.ru/xAeybQDcXYyqGA]

после деплоя страницы(на хостинге) подгружаются нормально(если по линкам кликать) - но как только делаю перезагрузку - вылетает 404-я
`+` например фавиконка не поттягивается - тоесть что то тут с путями не тот как я понимаю - но нет идей почему.
что я упускаю из виду?

Comment: проверьте опцию mode в роутере, должно быть `history`

Comment: http://joxi.ru/KAxpx8oHK4oDLA

если я прописываю данное св-во и значение у меня при деплое вот такая ошибка возникает

Comment: http://joxi.ru/MAjdQLoHkvyy8m
исправил на строчное св-во - ошибки нет при деплое - но проблему это не решает.

Comment: а, у вас Nuxt, не заметил

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо указать значение `universal` в свойстве `mode` в `nuxt.config.js`

https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-mode/

Comment: http://joxi.ru/n2YLbPaHejKJ7m
Оно уже было прописано.

Comment: сейчас ссылка рабочая ?
у вас пытается найти файлы по урлу /gps

Comment: webmaster.ayrveda.ru/dist/
вот рабочая ссылка

Comment: @MikeKharkov я бы так не сказал https://imgur.com/a/nYwV888

Comment: http://joxi.ru/L215QxzH06olk2
по выщеописанному линку у меня идет редирект на эту страницу и она работает(в мазилле)
(кроме вышеописанных проблем)